Can the filesystem that holds an SSH key be dismounted after the SSH connection is made?
I need to create long lasting SSH sessions with password-less keys without leaving the keys available in the clear once the session starts.
Is it possible to dismount the filesystem with the key without affecting the SSH session once the connection is made?
There is the possibility of the connection breaking and needing to be resumed without the command itself having to be run again, like some sshfs connections which appear to have been designed to last as long as needed without having to be restarted when the connection breaks.
In this kind of case is being able to read the key again necessary for the session to be resumed? Is this kind of situation the SSH system natively supports?

Put a strong passphrase on your SSH key, then there's no such thing as a "key in the clear."  Also, ssh typically requires pretty tight permissions on the key files, such that only you would be able to read them.  As for resuming a session, a properly-configured ssh-agent setup will keep your key active for whatever period of time you configure.

@JimL. Some long running activities such as backing up on a laptop to remote location over a slow link can be interrupted as the connection may break, the laptop may hibernate unexpectedly etc.
It is about granting access to encrypted filesystems which are only accessible at fixed limited times for short periods for tasks which need them to start up.


Is it possible to dismount the filesystem with the key without affecting the SSH session once the connection is made?

The SSH key is only used during the authentication phase; it does not encrypt data for the whole connection (…and even if it did, then the SSH client would just load it once and then keep it in memory – it would definitely not re-read the key from file for each and every packet).

In this kind of case is being able to read the key again necessary for the session to be resumed? Is this kind of situation the SSH system natively supports?

SSH does not support session resume at all. Either your TCP connection stays alive throughout network outages or you need to make a fresh SSH connection and go through all of the same authentication steps, requiring user credentials (private key, etc) to be available again. That's what sshfs does when you enable -o reconnect; it makes a completely new connection.
What you could do is to run an instance of ssh-agent and load the private key file into memory persistently, then let sshfs use the agent for the connection and all future re-connections. (The ssh-agent process allows the key to be used but not exported back to a file.) For example, this might work:
ssh-agent sshfs -o reconnect -o AddKeysToAgent=yes ...

or if AddKeysToAgent is not available:
ssh-agent bash -c "ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa && sshfs -o reconnect ..."

